# Visual Studio 2008 - Error updating JScript IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, jit, typelib

**Environment**

Windows 7 SP1 64bit

Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP

Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1

Web Site solution

---

**PROBLEM**

While working in my .aspx and .js files, I frequently (every couple of minutes) get the below popup message, which requires me to hit "No" and then resume working.

At about the same frequency, when I do any of the below actions:

- change views from the .aspx to a .js
- change views from the .js to the .aspx.cs
- click the "Save All" icon

it will give me the circular loading icon, and go to a "Not Responding" status for about 20 seconds.  After that time, I can resume whatever I was doing.

Full Page

[image: Full Page]

Full Popup

[image: Error Popup]

> Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger Popup Window
>
> An unhandled exception (''f' is null or not an object') occurred in
>   typelibbuilder.exe [8844].

Additionally, I do have the following warning message showing up in my Errors / Warnings toolbar.

> Error updating JScript IntelliSense: C:\Applications\Web
>   Interfaces\EcomIntranet\Plugins\jquery\js\jquery-1.9.1.js: Object
>   doesn't support this property or method @ 1318:1  C:\Applications\Web
>   Interfaces\EcomIntranet\Blacklist.aspx    1   1   C:...\EcomIntranet\

---

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS**

**1** I have tried putting the following text in a notepad file, and saving as a .reg, according to [this MSDN link here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2007/03/07/jscript-intellisense-march-ctp-gotchas-workarounds.aspx)... but it has not helped at all.

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\TypeLibBuilder,b03f5f7f11d50a3a]

**2** I've also taken all the JS file references to URL's, and downloaded the source directly to the project, so that it gets everything locally.

**3** I've also gone into Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JScript, and unchecked "Auto list members" and "Parameter Information".  The error is still happening... however the [8844] error code number does vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ran across this page

http://appendto.com/community/jquery-vsdoc/

which suggested to download the jquery -vsdoc file, and place it in the same directory as the referenced jquery file.

I did not need to add a script reference to it on my page, it simply needed to be included in the folder structure... the error has gone away!